# How to calculate average pixel intensity inside a laser line in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to write a code that calculates the speckle contrast of a laser line.
Here is an example of an image that I would be analyzing:

The image is black with white horizontal laser lines

[image: 1]

My current code is able to calculate the speckle contrast of the entire image, but this is not very useful since I only need to know the speckle contrast of the actual laser line.

Here is my code for reference:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics

# Open and display the image

im = Image.open(r"Picture1.jpg")
im.show()

# Create a list of pixel intensity values 

sequence_of_pixels = im.getdata()
pi = list(sequence_of_pixels)

# Calculate the standard deviation of the image

stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
standard_deviation, = stat.stddev
print("The standard deviation is: ", stat.stddev)

# Take the spatial averaging operator on pi and pi_squared 

pi_bracket = statistics.mean(pi)
print("The average pixel value is: ",pi_bracket)

# Next take the list of pixel values and square each value
# This makes a list of the squared elements of the original list of pixel values

def square(number):
    return number**2
squaring_iterator = map(square, pi)
pi_squared = list(squaring_iterator)

# Next take the average value of this new list 

pi_squared_bracket = statistics.mean(pi_squared)
print("The average squared pixel value is: ",pi_squared_bracket)

# Calculate the speckle average 
contrast = standard_deviation/pi_bracket
print("Speckle contrast is:", contrast)
```

My question is, how could I isolate the laser lines in the image so that I am only focusing on calculating the speckle contrast for that?

Comment: grayscale dilate" https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHfws.jpg then threshold. or do a median filter. something like that. if you don't like that noise passes through the morphology op, do a slight gaussian blur before the dilation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GucXY.jpg -- do you need me to show code for that? it's really not much to do

Comment: If you have code that you could show me, it would be greatly appreciated. I am really new to Python and don't understand all the terms for everything yet

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: morphological filtering or convolution will modify the gray distribution and introduce a bias on the contrast.

Comment: Your traces have a Gaussian profile with added noise (additive or multiplicative ?). How do you define the speckle contrast ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust it is the inverse of the signal-to-noise ratio in the image. Basically it is the spatial standard deviation divided by the mean pixel intensity. The issue is that my code currently is taking all the values in the image including the black background, but theoretically I should only be focusing on the speckle within the white lines

Comment: The equation for laser speckle contrast is C = ([<Pi^2> - <Pi>^2]^0.5)/<Pi>, where Pi is the greyscale intensity value seen by the ith pixel of the camera and <> denotes a spatial averaging operation.

Comment: So this is a variation coefficient. If the noise is multiplicative, you can sample anywhere inside the trace (but where signal is sufficient anyway). If the noise is additive, you need to sample precisely on the axis (or be able to correct the decay if you are off-axis).

Comment: Erratum: I think that even in the case of a multiplicative noise, sampling off-axis will introduce a bias. As the traces are pretty thin, this is not to be neglected.

Comment: I believe laser speckle is a multiplicative noise (from my understanding of the definition), so does that mean I would be able to get my answer by isolating any substantial part of the laser line and using the pixel values from that?

Comment: Try to take one central-most pixel per profile (say the one closest to the centroid).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there would be any way for Python to determine where the laser lines are and determine the centroid?

Comment: [Threshold the image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_thresholding.html) and then [skeletonize](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html).

Comment: @YvesDaoust we don't care about distribution (re your first comment). we care about calculating a *mask* for these lines, right? since that's the task, to get a mask in order to ignore most of the background.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: right, processing is allowed to determine the pixels of interest, provided the original values are used to compute the statistics. Anyway, the cross section of a line does not have constant intensity, and this introduces bias in the computation of the variation coefficient. I recommended to use the most central pixel only.